# why have my c++ compilers disappeard from vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was trying to write a c++ program, but when i went to compile it all my compilers had disappeared from the menu. I know theyre installed as ive used them before, but for some reason they arent showing up in vscode. The only thing thats showing up now is "cl.exe" before i also had the option of g++ and nothing has changed with the system so im very confused as to why this is.

I've tried restarting my computer, restarting vscode, checking if my compilers have somehow uninstalled themselves, but they all seem to be there. So i dont know why theyre missing.

Comment: Plugin updates? Configuration file modifications? System or compiler updates? Environment updates (like changing the system `PATH`)? There could be a thousand different small reasons for why this happened, and you really need to sit down and think about what happened between the last time it all worked, and it stopped working.

Comment: Nothings changed with the system they were there and then just gone

Comment: I'm sorry, but things just doesn't change as if by magic. Something must have happened, which lead to this problem. It might be hard to remember or even know all the little things that might have caused the problem, but there's still something done (by you, someone else, or by something simple as an automatic system update) to your system.

Comment: i dont know what it is then, because they worked 30 seconds before hand and then just disappeared. So whatever has changed i likely dont even have a way of figuring out

Comment: Perhaps someone knows, where the list of compilers is stored or you could reinstall without losing your settings?